# How to write userid special chars in sqlldr?

Tags: sql-loader

I have a problem

my db userid is
id = test_test
pw = test_test1!2@

so I wrote like this

sqlldr "test_test/test_test1!2@"@IP:port/sid control='path'

but it shows "ORA-12154 TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"

I need help

Answer (score 0):

Just change your password and don't use the '@' sign.  Save yourself a headache.

```
ALTER USER test_test identified by new_password_here
```